# Inline Editing of View data used in a repeat

Tags: xpages

I have a repeat control using a view as the datasource with a custom control within the repeat.  The custom control is made up of a panel with two tables.  One table has computed fields with an Edit button and the other has editable fields with a Save and Cancel button.  The Edit and Cancel buttons work as needed, but the Save button gives a NotesDocument.save() is null error.  I have already narrowed the issue down to the error occurring on the edoc.save() line by commenting out all prior lines.  I even tried to do an edoc.lock(), but got the same error.

```
var edoc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(viewScope.get('docid'));
edoc.replaceItemValue('Ext_1',viewScope.get('ext_1'));
edoc.replaceItemValue('DID',viewScope.get('did'));
edoc.replaceItemValue('Mobile',viewScope.get('mobile'));
try {
edoc.save();
} catch(e) {
print(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can you show a little more of an example xsp code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage of a DocID in the viewScope and a repeat control doesn't seem right. You want to add a custom property to your custom control called DocID and then instead of

```
    database.getDocumentByUNID(viewScope.get("docid"));
```

You do:

```
    database.getDocumentByUNID(compositeData.DocID);
```

This was you can be sure that you get the document that was in that view for that row.
What you also might consider, instead of all the manual steps (the ones you commented out) have a panel with a DocumentDataSource and then simply bind your input fields to that one. Handover of id via custom property and "`IgnoreRequestParameter = true`

Then you simply do a rowDoc.save() (presuming you named the datasource rowDoc) and you don't need to recycle anything. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: It's `ignoreRequestParams`, Stephan. ;)

Comment: @Timtripcony spelling was never my domain, praise to property sheets and dropdowns

Comment: @stwissel @Timtripcony

I have passed custom properties from a XPage to a custom control, but with my custom control being nested in my repeat every record ends up in edit mode.  Here is my XPage code:
    `<xp:panel id="repeatpanel">`
    `<xp:this.data>`
    `<xp:dominoView var="phoneportal" viewName="By Name">`
    `</xp:dominoView>`
    `</xp:this.data>`
    `<ul>`
    `<xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{phoneportal}" var="buscards"`
    `disableOutputTag="true">`
    `<li>`
    `<xc:buscard></xc:buscard>`
    `</li>`
    `</xp:repeat>`
    `</ul>`
    `</xp:panel>`

Comment: Here is the `<xc:buscard>`
`<xp:panel>
<xp:table> visible when not being edited
<xp:tr>
<xp:td></xp:td> computed fields binded to repeat with edit button
</xp:tr>
</xp:table>
<xp:table> visible when being edited
<xp:tr>
<xp:td></xp:td> editable fields binded to repeat with save and cancel buttons; save button throws previously stated null error
</xp:tr>
</xp:table>
</xp:panel>

Comment: The document data source needs to be inside the custom control you want 2 custom parameters: DocId  and isedit (boolean, defaults to false). You bind the DocId to the repeat and the data source of the inner panel to compositeData.